# Seeding Laravel with array of ID doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I try to do seeding on a pivot table.
Here is my code

```
public function run()
{
    // Get array of ids
    $teacherIds = DB::table('teachers')->pluck('id');
    $courseIds  = DB::table('courses')->pluck('id');

    // Seed course_teacher table
    foreach ((range(1, 1)) as $index)
    {
        DB::table('course_teacher')->insert(
            [
                'teacher_id' => $teacherIds[array_rand( (array) $teacherIds)],
                'course_id' => $courseIds[array_rand( (array) $courseIds)]
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

I added (array) because I had an error that I was giving an object while it wanted an array.

But since I have another error `undefined index:`

Can you help me ? Thank you very much

Comment: On which line are you getting that error?

Comment: Print the result of `$teacherIds`, show it here what it give?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make sure you get an array when getting `$teacherIds` and `$courseIds`, add the [`toArray`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-toarray) function to make sure you are getting an array and not a Collection object.

```
// Get array of ids
$teacherIds = DB::table('teachers')->pluck('id')->toArray();
$courseIds  = DB::table('courses')->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

By doing this, you don't need to cast the array in the `array_rand` function either.

**Update:**

Even better would be to use the [`random`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-random) function. This function will choose a random element for you.

```
$teacherIds = DB::table('teachers')->pluck('id');
$courseIds  = DB::table('courses')->pluck('id');

DB::table('course_teacher')->insert(
    [
        'teacher_id' => $teacherIds->random(),
        'course_id' => $courseIds->random()
    ]
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much !  Your solution works well and I understand better why!